# Dutch postalcode in Mapbox Geocoding API

Tags: mapbox, geocoding

*update* it was a bug and they fixed it!

Dutch postalcodes contains 4 digits and 2 letters.
When entering 4 digits, it finds the global postalcode location, but when you add 2 letters (which corresponds to a street) the response doenst return the right location.

For example: 1012 returns a general postalcode location in Amsterdam. But when you enter 1012 AW it returns totally different results (different cities even). But it should return a specific location within the 1012 postalcode area.

**url**
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${search}.json

**params**

```
{
  language: 'nl',
  country: 'NL',
  limit: 1,
  access_token: config.accessToken,
  types: 'address,place,poi'
}
```

The postal code that comes back don't have the two letter digits. How to get Mapbox to add the two letters?

Example response.

It is 4694 but it should be 4694EG

```
{  
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "query":[  
      "***",
      "***"
   ],
   "features":[  
      {  
         "id":"address.7144861498943104",
         "type":"Feature",
         "place_type":[  
            "address"
         ],
         "relevance":0.75,
         "properties":{  
            "accuracy":"point"
         },
         "text_nl":"Beatrixlaan",
         "place_name_nl":"Beatrixlaan 2, 4694 Scherpenisse, Nederland",
         "text":"Beatrixlaan",
         "place_name":"Beatrixlaan 2, 4694 Scherpenisse, Nederland",
         "center":[  
            4.103576,
            51.546267
         ],
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               4.103576,
               51.546267
            ]
         },
         "address":"2",
         "context":[  
            {  
               "id":"postcode.10605073597498580",
               "text_nl":"4694",
               "text":"4694"
            },
            {  
               "id":"place.5585596482812836",
               "wikidata":"Q2381830",
               "text_nl":"Scherpenisse",
               "language_nl":"nl",
               "text":"Scherpenisse",
               "language":"nl"
            },
            {  
               "id":"region.13950781060383020",
               "short_code":"NL-ZE",
               "wikidata":"Q705",
               "text_nl":"Zeeland",
               "language_nl":"nl",
               "text":"Zeeland",
               "language":"nl"
            },
            {  
               "id":"country.9349515904622050",
               "short_code":"nl",
               "wikidata":"Q55",
               "text_nl":"Nederland",
               "language_nl":"nl",
               "text":"Nederland",
               "language":"nl"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "attribution":"NOTICE: © 2019 Mapbox and its suppliers. All rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service (https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This response and the information it contains may not be retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare."
}
```

Comment: What does your query look like? Can you post the full link without your token?

Comment: I've added the response to my answer. ;)

Comment: @BDD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_the_Netherlands

Comment: I think postcode.10605073597498580 should be  4694EG instead of 4694

Comment: @RichardLindhout what query did you use? I am not getting a good match against a dutch zipcode. I need to get the address from zipcode + house number

Comment: @TomAalbers I'm having problems too, sometimes I don't get the street name when an address is a company. I'm now using Google Maps for this.. :(

Comment: @RichardLindhout I'm trying to get Mapbox to return an exact address for a house number/postcode combination. You seem to have managed this, could you please share the search text?

Comment: I don't know anymore. I switched too the Google API for these use cases since mapbox don't return addresses for points of interests or something like that.

You need forward geocoding
https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#forward-geocoding

Here is the style guide for the search text
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/address-geocoding-format-guide/

E.g.
123 Main St 02111 Boston MA